# finding docker images with tag and name

Tags: linux, unix, shell, shell-scripting

when I do docker images I have below docker images as list where there are images with multiple tag and also image with latest tag value.

```
REPOSITORY                            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
m1                                  latest              40febdb010b1        15 minutes ago      479MB
m2                                    130                 fab5a122127a        4 weeks ago         2.74GB
m2                                    115                 5a2ee5c5f5e5        4 weeks ago         818MB
m3                                    111                 dd91a7f68e3d        5 weeks ago         818MB
m3                                     23                  0657662756f6        5 weeks ago         2.22GB
m4                                     23                  0657662756f6        5 weeks ago         2.22GB
```

While I do `for i in {docker image save -o <imagename>.tar}` I would like to only save the images as tar for the tag with higher numbers but except any docker image with `latest` tag and docker image name as `m4`
How this can be achieved in one liner command.

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation say](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/), you can simply use the `<image>:<tag>` syntax.

For exemple : `docker save -o fedora-latest.tar fedora:latest`

You can compress it with gzip with the gollowing in order to get a `.tar.gz` image :

```
docker save myimage:latest | gzip > myimage_latest.tar.gz
```